# Tardare e Ritardare

Tags: word-usage, verbs, word-choice, difference

Qual è la differenza tra "tardare" e "ritardare"? Ci sono casi in cui va usato preferibilmente uno dei due?

Mi sembra che ritardare richieda un oggetto, ritardare qualcosa, è una interpretazione corretta?

Comment: Hai dato un'occhiata, per cominciare, qui: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tardare e http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ritardare ?

Comment: @DaG grazie per il link, però non chiarisce del tutto: quando è meglio uno e quando è meglio l'altro?

Comment: Sicuramente qualcuno darà una risposta compiuta, ma intanto da queste voci si vede che, come hai intuito, “tardare” è per lo più intransitivo e solo raramente ammette un oggetto, mentre “ritardare” ammette entrambe le costruzioni.

Comment: @ErniBrown Benvenuto su ItalianSE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Tardare* e *ritardare* sono due verbi molto simili, ma non del tutto intercambiabili.

La differenza più notevole è nella forma transitiva, dove *ritardare* viene quasi sempre preferito a *tardare*. Ad esempio si dice "dobbiamo *ritardare* la riunione" e non "dobbiamo *tardare* la riunione".

Nella forma intransitiva *tardare* ha più il significato di impiegare molto tempo, fare tardi, mentre *ritardare* richiama più direttamente l'arrivare dopo il termine prefissato. Così "non tardare" significa fai presto, mentre "non ritardare" significa non arrivare in ritardo. Questa differenza però è meno marcata, ed entrambi i verbi possono avere lo stesso significato.

Ritardare si usa di più nel senso assoluto, per cui si dice più spesso "il treno *ritarda*" oppure "il treno *tarda* ad arrivare".

Nel significato di rallentare o posticipare qualcosa, si usa quasi esclusivamente *ritardare*; ad esempio *ritardare* una risposta, una reazione chimica, un lavoro.

Se si vuole indicare che un orologio sta indietro, si dice che *ritarda* e non che *tarda*.

Infine gli aggettivi *ritardante* e *ritardato*, che derivano dai participi di *ritardare*, hanno significati in molti casi particolari diversi dai participi di *tardare*.